# Setting cache control for css, images and js in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, tomcat6

I am trying to set the cache for CSS, images and JS files using the following third party library cachefilter2.0.jar.

The corresponding library documentation can be found [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/setting-cache-filter-tomcat-or-jboss-static-files)

The jar file can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/cache-filter/downloads/detail?name=cachefilter-2.0.jar&can=2&q=)

```
<filter>
<filter-name>imagesCache</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>static</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
    <param-value>2592000</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>cssCache</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
        <param-value>604800</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>jsCache</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>private</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
        <param-value>216000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cssCache</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jsCache</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>imagesCache</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The above method is working perfectly for sub directories in my local development server using eclipse. I am doing the same thing in external server but it is not working for sub directories in my external server.

I had tried creating the own filter still facing the same problem.